# Class Inheritance without attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, rdlc, report-designer

I have the following Class

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    .... a lot more properties
}
```

Is there a way to inherit/have a copy of the class without the attributes, without having to duplicate the class code twice?

Real problem explained:
I'm using an RDLC report, and I use the class as the datasource.

Problem is that the Report Designer does not like this, and gives me the following message:

> *Failed to get properties of data source 'Item' because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly
>   System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral....... Or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.*

Comment: i think that setting `[AttributeUsage (Inherited = False)]` above the class will help you

Comment: Inheriting a class means whatever loads the derived class loading and understanding the base class, AFAIK. So you can't derive to remove the issue. I don't think there's any way to remove (or derive and add) the attributes that isn't (roughly) the same amount of work.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.ComponentModel?

Comment: @affanBajwa sealed will prevent from other classes from inheriting from it and that's not what he wants

Comment: @ZoharPeled, if you mean to the class, of course, otherwise i would be getting compile/intellisense errors. and if you mean to the Report Designer, I don't think there is a way to do that, the error message is displayed in a messagebox.

Comment: @styx, when I put the attributeUsage on top of the class, I get the following error: 
Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute

Comment: @Amro i though so, so basically the answer is no

Answer (score 0):

No, such information (like base types and attributes on the properties/methods) from base class is always inherited. Some is required to instantiate the class (like assembly that contains base class) and some will be required when code tries to do reflection (which probably what happens in this case).

Your options are either figure out why that assembly is not found by designer or have some sort of duplicate class setup for design time. Maybe just an interface with the same properties would be enough in your case.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to not duplicate the code, I think using an Interface would be interesting, (correct me if I'm wrong) wouldn't that require me to write more code compared to duplicating the class?